# Postgresql combining date, time and microseconds into timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a table with the following fields:

```
my_date     my_time     my_time2
2017-04-14  10:00:01    286115
```

How do I combine these fields into timestamp column like `2017-04-14 10:00:01.286115`?
Unfortunately `select my_date+my_time+my_time2 from my_table` works fine only for the first two fields. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the data types?

Comment: date,time,int4 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select date '2017-04-14' + time '10:00:01' + 286115 * interval '1usec';
┌────────────────────────────┐
│          ?column?          │
╞════════════════════════════╡
│ 2017-04-14 10:00:01.286115 │
└────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```